# display specific value from Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I want to show value in gridview for specific user. In 'Test Query' it works fine, but didn't show value on page. What's wrong?

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="698px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" DataKeyNames="Idoferty">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Idoferty" HeaderText="Idoferty" SortExpression="Idoferty" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ofety_stopowiczeV1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Idoferty] FROM [rezerwacje] WHERE ([user] = @user)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:SessionParameter Name="user" SessionField="User.Identity.Name" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

SELECT statement

```
SELECT [Idoferty] FROM [rezerwacje] WHERE ([user] = @user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here isn't that your query is failing or that the `GridView` is misbehaving, it is because `User.Identity.Name` is not a property of the `Session` object.

`User.Identity.Name` is a property of the `HttpContext` class, usually retrieved from `HttpContext.Current`, the currently executing HTTP request context.

If you want to use this property from the `Session` object, you will have to set it explicitly, for example:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

And then in your markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ofety_stopowiczeV1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Idoferty] FROM [rezerwacje] WHERE ([user] = @user)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="user" SessionField="UserName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Alternatively, it is also possible to set a basic parameter with a default value directly on the control, as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ofety_stopowiczeV1ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Idoferty] FROM [rezerwacje] WHERE ([user] = @user)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserName" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Then in code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["UserName"].DefaultValue = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Note: either `HttpContext.Current.User` or just `User` is valid on an ASP.Net `Page` object as the `User` object on the `Page` class is a shortcut to `HttpContext.Current.User`, as per the docs:

> This property uses the HttpContext object's User property to determine
>   where the request originates.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx

Docs for `HttpContext`: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpContext(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpContext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)